# elastic search uri call return one field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, elasticsearch, return, uri

i'm using elastic search in my project. For many reasons, i have to call Elastic by the URI. like : 
"http://localhost:9200//demo/localetranslatemodel/_search?default_operator=AND&q=localeId%3Adaefa52a-cada-4370-9ae5-6bcfb50a9cf8+name%3AlblCommon_PartCost"

and this return :

```
{

    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 8.272978,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "demo",
            "_type": "localetranslatemodel",
            "_id": "31bb0b3f-ace5-4007-b619-009f3e76bafc",
            "_score": 8.272978,
            "_source": {
                "translate": "Part cost",
                "localeId": "daefa52a-cada-4370-9ae5-6bcfb50a9cf8",
                "name": "lblCommon_PartCost",
                "id": "31bb0b3f-ace5-4007-b619-009f3e76bafc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

so my question is : Can i return only "translate : "Part cost" ? Or, very better for me, only "Part cost" ? 
I'm using a HttpClient for calling the Api, in a ASP .NET project. 
thank you very much for the usefull answer, i'm trying to do this for a week

All solutions are good for me if i ask something impossible. (Like only return the _source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. Response filtering can do that.

Read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering

Also you can ask for specific fields instead of getting the full _source field. Depends on what you really need. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-source-filtering.html

Comment: Oh, thank's you i'm now returning :
{
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_source": {
                    "translate": "Part cost"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

But i clearly can't return only "Part cost" right ? I mean only the value

Comment: I don’t think so.